# this.$scope is null in $postLink() of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
class pageController {

    constructor($scope, MyEditableGrid) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.MyEditableGrid = MyEditableGrid;
        this.myEditableGrid = {
            appScope: this.$scope,
            .....
        }
    }
    $postLink() {
        this.$scope.$on('message', function (event, data) {
            console.log(this.MyEditableGrid); ==> null?
            console.log(this.$scope);  ==> null?
            console.log(this.myEditableGrid); ==> null
        }
    }  
}
```

The message was broadcast from service.js:

$rootScope.$broadcast('message',data);

the error message in browser inspector for console.log(this.MyEditableGrid):

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyEditableGrid' of null**

The error message in browser inspector for console.log(this.$scope):

**TypeError: Cannot read property '$scope' of null**

Comment: I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you made EditableGrid a property of your class, not the $scope.

You can with access it with this.EditableGrid, or add it to the $scope in the constructor.

--UPDATE AFTER QUESTION CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED--

You are losing the scope of `this` by using `function(..)` rather than the fat arrow function which preserves the scope of `this`.

Try this:

```
this.$scope.$on('message', (event, data) => { 
  // this still points to the class instance
}):
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, there is mistake in my post.

Comment: the following works : this.$scope.$on('message', (event, response) => { console.log(this.MyEditableGrid);        });